# Trying to make the loop parallel with GPars fails

Tags: grails, groovy, gpars

I have a loop as shown in the example below which works. I am trying to make it parallel, but it gives the error. How to make it parallel (or where is the problem)?

> ```
> Message: No signature of method: org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet.eachParallel()
> is applicable for argument types: (com.example.ExampleController$_getOrgsWithSpec..
> ```

```
// Example domain class
Organization {
    OrgProfile orgProfile
    IndProfile indProfile
}

//same for IndProfile
OrgProfile { 
    static mapping = {
        specs lazy:false
        cache true
    }
    static hasMany = [
        specs: Specs
    ]
}
// --------------------------------

//Controller methods
// Normal code (works)
def getOrgsWithSpec = { orgs ->
    def s = []  
    orgs.each { o ->
        if (o.type == 1) { //just an example
            o.orgProfile?.specs?.findAll { m ->
                if (m.id == specId) {
                    s.push(o)
                }
            }
        } else if (o.type == 2) {
            o.indProfile?.specs?.findAll { m ->
                if (m.id == specId) {
                    s.push(o)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return s
}

// With GPars (not working)
def getOrgsWithSpec = { orgs ->
    def s = []
    GParsPool.withPool {
        orgs.eachParallel { o ->
            if (o.type == 1) {
                o.orgProfile?.specs?.findAllParallel { m ->
                    if (m.id == specId) {
                        s.push(o)
                    }
                }
            } else if (o.type == 2) {
                o.indProfile?.specs?.findAllParallel { m ->
                    if (m.id == specId) {
                        s.push(o)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return s
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you wrapped the body of the getOrgsWithSpec() method in a withPool block?

withPool {
  orgs.eachParallel {...}
}

Also, mind you that using the 's' accumulator inside eachParallel() needs to be protected, perhaps by making it a synchronized list. So collectParallel{} would probably be a better choice.

Comment: Yes, I am using `withPool`. See the second function in controllers in the above example. The accumulator `s` is not within the pool. I tried with `collectParallel{}` and I think I got mysql connection closed error. (Away from the code at present).

Comment: I'm concerned about the s.push() calls not being synchronized in any way and yet being called from multiple threads.

Comment: I can't really thing of a reason of eachParallel() not being present on orgs, while you're inside a withPool block.

Comment: Also, you'll have to create nested withPool (or withExistingPool) blocks inside eachParallel for findAllParallel() to work, since the eachParallel body is run with a new (pooled) thread.

withPool {pool ->
  eachParallel {
    withExistingPool(pool) {
      x.findAllParallel()
    }
  }
}

Comment: Oh! Missed the nested `withPool` block. I think that should work. (AFK). Also thanks for pointing out the scoping of variable `s`. Now I get it. The `s` should be inside the `withPool` block. Perhaps `collectParallel` is more appropriate. (These things took some time to sync in ;)).